# Remove space between rows in GridView

Tags: android, android-imageview, baseadapter, android-gridview

I know this has been asked in many different ways in StackOverflow but none of the answers seem to fit with my problem.

As it can be seen in this picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDKtS.jpg), I get an ugly space at the bottom of the GridView because the rows don't stretch proportionally to cover all the height of the GridView. I have tried so many different codes that it is useless to write them all here. What I will do instead is to show the pieces of my code that I currently have and that are relevant for the problem.

I first calculate the dimensions of the GridView before displaying the images inside of it. I want 3 columns and 3 rows, that's why inside setDimensions I divide by COLUMNS in both cases (because it is a constant int with value of 3):

```
private void setDimensions() {

    ViewTreeObserver vto = mGridView.getViewTreeObserver();     

    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mGridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);         

            int displayWidth = mGridView.getMeasuredWidth();          
            int displayHeight = mGridView.getMeasuredHeight();

            mColumnWidth = displayWidth / COLUMNS;
            mColumnHeight = displayHeight / COLUMNS;

            display(getApplicationContext());
        }
    });
}




private static void display(Context context) {
    ArrayList<ImageView> imgs = new ArrayList<>();
    ImageView image;


    /*

    ...More code
     */

    mGridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(imgs, mColumnWidth, mColumnHeight));
}
```

My getView() method of the adapter class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {            

    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = imgs.get(position);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }


    android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams(mColumnWidth, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);


    return imageView;
}
```

One of the solutions I've come across many times when searching for it is to inflate a layout for the view (in this case, for the ImageView) and then use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` for the ImageView, but this has no effect.

As required by Ferran, this is the code I try inflating the ImageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
```

The code above would be in combination with this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        imageView = (ImageView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);

    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setMinimumHeight(mColumnHeight/3);
    imageView.setMinimumWidth(mColumnWidth/3);


    return imageView;
}
```

And the result would be a white screen of death: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRfdZ.jpg

Comment: Do you want to increase the space between rows or to stretch the image to fill the whole available space (this will change the proportionality)?

Comment: Hello @Ferran I want to stretch the image to fill the whole available space, I don't care if proportionality is lost. But I would like to have the rows stretch equally. Even though I don't care about the pictures stretching, I do need the rows to be of equal height.

Comment: Try This:- add this in your ImageView--> android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: @ChaudharyAmar Please check last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your Activity find the height of your screen:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

scrHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Then, in your adapter, set the minimum height of your items

```
itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null); // the layout of your item
itemView.setMinimumHeight(scrHeight/3);
```

Comment: I had already tried that solution. This is what I get from that: https://imgur.com/a/pJA8wKV

Comment: So, please, share your item layout xml.

Comment: Code updated @Ferran  The photo I showed you previously was without an item layout (I don't need it because it's just an ImageView). But if I inflated the ImageView layout I would get a white screen of death right away

Comment: ok, reviewing your first `getView`, you are setting the `LayoutParams` to `WRAP_CONTENT`, what about using `MATCH_PARENT` instead?

Comment: Yes, but I mean without inflating the layout.

Comment: Yes, without inflating the layout.